# Spring @SqsListener - get queue name

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk, spring-messaging

I understand that with Springs `@SqsListener` annotation I can listen to multiple queues with the same listener. As per documentation:

```
public @interface SqsListener {

    /**
     * List of queues. Queues can be defined by their logical/physical name or URL.
     * @return list of queues
     */
    String[] value() default {};
```

So an example in Kotlin could look something like this:

```
@SqsListener(value = ["queue1", "queue2"], deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ALWAYS)
@MessageMapping
fun testListeningToMultipleQueues(@Payload myPayloadObject: MyPayloadObject, @Header("myCustomHeader") myCustomHeader: String) {
    logger.info("Message received, but not sure from which queue")
}
```

**Is there some way inside the `testListeningToMultipleQueues` method to know wether the message came from `queue1` or `queue2`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use this header:

```
@Header("LogicalResourceId") receivedQueue: String
```

Or `lookupDestination` if `LogicalResourceId` comes as an ARN.